# Primitivable function

Tags: continuity

> Let $f \colon\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ be an increasing
> function. Define $F\colon \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ as $$F(x)=\lim_{y  \downarrow x}f(y), \text{ for every }x \in \mathbb
>  R.$$  Prove that if $F$ is continuous then $f$ is primitivable.

My attempt:

First of all, I noticed that the value of function $F$ at an arbitrary point $x$ is equal to the right-sided limit of $f$ at the point in question.

It goes without saying that every monotonous function has a right-sided limit at every point. Therefore, I stated that the function $F$ is correctly defined.

Since the function $F$ is continuous, I guess that the function $f$ is continuous. Thus, it has to be primitivable.

But I'm not quite sure that from the continuity of $F$, we also have the continuity of $f$. May somebody help me with this part?

Comment: Definition of "primitivable" is found at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1744669/442

Comment: An increasing function has only jump discontinuities. It it has one then $F$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f$ is not continuous at some $x_0\in\mathbb R$. Then, due to the monotonicity, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that either $f(x_0)+\varepsilon\leq f(x)$ for all $x>x_0$, or $f(x)\leq f(x_0)-\varepsilon$ for all $x<x_0$. We only consider the first case, the second is treated similarly.
Then $F(x_0)=\lim_{x\downarrow x_0}f(x)\geq f(x_0)+\varepsilon$. For $y<x<x_0$ we have $f(y)\leq f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ and hence $F(y)=\lim_{x\downarrow y}f(x)\leq f(x_0)$. Thus, $F(y)\leq f(x_0)<f(x_0)+\varepsilon\leq F(x_0)$ for all $y<x_0$, showing that $F$ is discontinuous at $x_0$.